# Passing QUERY_STRING to RedirectMatch like rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Need to create a mod_rewrite rules to provide SEO friendly api.

Some like:

```
https://server.app/api/Toronto/parks/
```

Must return output of:

```
https://server.app/cgi-bin/api.cgi?domain=Toronto&script=parks.cgi
```

### Background

RedirectMatch works fine, but I loose the query string variable. *And don't need to redirect to an ugly URL.*

I try a RewriteRule without success. Throw an 404 Not Found.

Note:

- DocumentRoot: `/var/www/html`
- Directory `/var/www/html/api` nor Alias/ScriptAlias to `/api` don't exist.

### Try 1

```
RedirectMatch "^/api/(.*)/(.*)/" "/cgi-bin/api.cgi?domain=$1&script=$2.cgi"
```

Missing Query String variable in URLs like:

```
https://server.app/api/Toronto/parks/?other=value
```

### Try 2

```
RewriteRule "^/api/(.*)/(.*)/" "/cgi-bin/api.cgi?domain=$1&script=$2.cgi" [QSA]
```

Error 404 Not Found.

### Expected results

Call to:

```
https://server.app/api/Toronto/parks/?other=value
```

Must work like:

```
https://server.app/cgi-bin/api.cgi?domain=Toronto&script=parks.cgi&other=value
```

Comment: Are your rules in .htaccess or in .conf file?

Comment: Global conf file. No Directory rule, no VirtualHost rule.

Comment: Your Try 2. should work (I tested it), if it does not work, something else is wrong, not the rule

Comment: You can add `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6` to your .conf and reload apache, you will be able to see detailed rewrite log in your apache error log.